# use complex analysis to prove countably many points on plane (not on the same line) cannot have pairwise distances all equal to integers

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

This is Exercise 58 in Chapter one of our textbook Function Theory of One Complex Variable by Greene and Krantz:

Let $z_1, z_2, \ldots$ be a countable set of distinct complex numbers. If $|z_j-z_k|$ is an integer for every $j,k$ (the integer may depend on $j$ and $k$), then prove that the $\{z_j\}$ lie on a single straight line.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I tried to read the paper by Anning and Erd"os https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-08/S0002-9904-1945-08407-9/S0002-9904-1945-08407-9.pdf, but I couldn't understand it and it does not use complex analysis.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33731/do-infinitely-many-points-in-a-plane-with-integer-distances-lie-on-a-line)

Comment: Thank you! I found in that question a follow up of the above mentioned paper by Erd\"os https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-12/S0002-9904-1945-08490-0/S0002-9904-1945-08490-0.pdf, which contains a shorter proof

Comment: Is there any way to do it by complex analysis?

Comment: Does the textbook imply that there is a complex analysis solution? Maybe it simply wants you to get used to metric geometry of the complex plane. What else is discussed in the chapter 1?

Comment: Chapter 1 establishes the concept of complex differentiable, which includes Cauchy-Riemann equations, and also gives several direct properties of holomorphic functions and holomorphic polynomials.

Comment: @Lingling Then, most likely, they do not expect you to use any complex analysis for this problem.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I think I'd better close this question on mathstack, but I don't know how to do it.